# How to center image using CSS without white border

Tags: html, css

Here is my CSS and HTML code. I want to put a single image in the center and this works except there is a weird white border around the image. I have tried `border:none;` and `border:0;`

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Food.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">

</head>


<body>
<img border="0" id="image" class="centered" />

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -182px;
  margin-left: -153px;

}

img#image{
   /*I think this is where the issue is caused*/
    width:337px;
    height:219px;
    background-image: url('soon_comp.png');
    background-color: transparent;
}


body {
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgb(15,15,30);
    border-color:transparent;
    border:0px;
}
```

Comment: why not put your image source in `img` instead of the `css`? e.g. `<img id="image" src="soon_comp.png" class="centered"/>`

Comment: And you are sure that the image itself doesn't have white border? Not being sarcastic, just that i've done it myself a few times before realizing that the white border was part of image itself and not due to HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know why you're setting a background image for an img tag, I would rather to use a div  or span tag instead. But, if you really want to do this, try to add to your img#image CSS rule:

```
img#image{
  content: '';
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you tried to simplify your code but:

1) The src of the image is missing: `<img src= "myimage.jpg" />`.

2) Don't use `border="0"` instead in CSS use `border:none`

3) Don't give a background to an image, maybe instead use a division.

Besides that I didn't see any white border when I tested your code.
Can you be more specific maybe?

Comment: Also make sure that soon_comp.png is exactly width:337px; height:219px; if not you will definitely see some white borders or the image repeat, but I will strongly suggest to use the image with the source or a division with a background image.